# change ip inside link using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, ip

so my goal is to change ip address in link with user's current ip.
This is script for returing current user ip address.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var userip;
  document.write(userip); // write to html
</script>
```

Link example:

```
www.mysite.com/data/uploads/file.mp3?e=14512&ip=IPHERE&amp=blbablaba&next=fasfass
```

How can I make to write user's ip to "IPHERE" place and link will look like:

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/data/uploads/file.mp3?e=14512&ip=123.123.123.123&amp=blbablaba&next=fasfass">link with ip</a>
```

without changing anything else.

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot get the users IP in JavaScript.

Comment: @andlrc he is getting it with the api: https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for all a tags and replace href:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a')).forEach(function(a) {
    a.href = a.href.replace(/IPHERE/g, userip);
});
```

Comment: or `var links = document.links; for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) ....` why the long and not fully supported way around

Comment: Thanks for reply, jcubic. Any chance of working fiddle?

Comment: In ES6, instead of `[].slice.call` you can use `Array.from()`

Comment: Thank you! :) Any chance of doing it inside a div but with src of image? 
<div><img src="link"></div>

Comment: Thank you :) I have also tried it with <source> inside <video> tag, but video doesnt seem to reload to new link after the address has been changed :/

Comment: You can try to ask another question.